# Usage of "to", "of", and "for" in sentences

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

From sentences given below, Which one is correct? As I always confuse to use between **"to"**, **"of"**, and **"for"** words in sentences.

> India is home **to** 56 of the world’s 2000 powerful companies.

or

> India is home **of** 56 of the world’s 2000 powerful companies.

or

> India is home **for** 56 of the world’s 2000 powerful companies.

Please give justification, if possible.

Comment: …56 of the world's 2000 _most_ powerful companies.

Answer (score 1):

Both are widely used. In fact, you missed **one more** like that.

> [some place] is home *for*.... something

However, it's [not used very frequently.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3780/home-to-or-home-for)

So, to answer this question broadly, the phrase `home to/of` is okay and understandable. Both are in practice.

Recommendation: To know the *subtle* difference, visit the page of ELU I linked.

---

Suggestion: Why don't you go for...

> *Out of the top 2000 powerful companies in the world, 56 are located in India.*

Comment: In the case of using "to", it would be more natural to say "Out of *the*  top 2000 (most) powerful companies...", or from the question "India is *the* home of 56 of..."